# How Do You Copy Range of Cells Until Last Row from Another Workbook in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy a range of cells until the last used row from another workbook that my main workbook has already opened and activated.  The range needs to begin at C2 over to Column M and then until the first blank row.

The Code I have so far copies the right cell columns, but extends down past the used rows into blank rows.  I've attached a screenshot.  Pasting the copied cells into the main workbook is successful.

[image: !(http://tinypic.com/r/29uouwh/9)]

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\user\Documents\Maintenance Department\General\Equipment Documentation\Holding Furnace\Readings\Data Logs\Flow Sensor Monthly Alarm Log - Inductor.xlsx")
ThisWorkbook.Activate

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("Flow Sensor Monthly Alarm Log - Inductor.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:M2" & LastRow).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: That is because you are getting the last row from the worksheet to which you are copying not the workbook that just got opened: `LastRow = Workbooks("Flow Sensor Monthly Alarm Log - Inductor.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I replaced the line with the code in your reply and the copied cells extend down to row 26 now instead of row 21

Comment: Also `Range("C2:M2" & LastRow)` will return the wrong row, if `LastRow` is 6 then the range becomes `Range("C2:M26")` and not `Range("C2:M6")`  You want `Range("C2:M" & LastRow)`

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Workbook` and `Worksheet` object instead of `Activate` :

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim DestSht As Worksheet
Dim SourceSht As Worksheet

Set DestSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\Maintenance Department\General\Equipment Documentation\Holding Furnace\Readings\Data Logs\Flow Sensor Monthly Alarm Log - Inductor.xlsx")
Set SourceSht = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = SourceSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

SourceSht.Range("C2:M" & LastRow).Copy
DestSht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```